# Twist a single line matrix in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I have a single line matrix made with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [matrix,fill=white!20,draw=blue] (my matrix) at (3,2)
{
\node(a) {40}; & \node{AE}; & \node{B0}; & \node(b) {05}; & \node(b) {05};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to "twist" this matrix along a curve (I would like to
illustrate something like a flow ...) and to "open it" at both ends?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and state your dependencies. Your `replace ampersand with` doesn't work work for me. Are you using a recent CVS version?

Comment: OK. I removed the "replace ampersand". I am using texlive 2010. The code I show compile without problem. My question is about the possibility to "twist" this matrix. (thanks percusse)

Comment: I have completed your code, however effectively you can do the same with :`\matrix [fill=white!20,draw=blue,matrix of nodes] (my matrix) 
{40 & AE & B0& 05 & 05 \\};`. You don't need to enter `\node` in each cell. Moreover, I don't think `matrix` is the way to go but you can do that with text decorations. See manual Section 30.6

Comment: thanks percusse; il will have a look to text decorations !

Comment: How to do you want to specify the curve?

Answer (score 8):

¡Viva la *Answering the unanswered movement* !

I have written a simple code demonstrating the detail in my comment. The details are given in the manual section 30.6 (version 2.10)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines,opacity=0.3] (-2,-1) grid[step=1cm] (4,5);
\matrix [fill=white!20,draw=blue,matrix of nodes] (my matrix) {40 & AE & B0 & 05 & 05 \\};
\draw[decoration={raise=-1.2mm,
                    text along path,
                    text align={center,left indent=2.5cm},
                    text={40 AE B0 05 05},
                    %
                },
                postaction={decorate},
                double,
                double distance=5mm,
                blue] (2,0) -- (2,4) -- (0.5,1.5) -- ++(10:3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the text might get weird while trying hard to follow the curve so use responsibly. I think I overdid this when I was testing out different options but anyway here is an image with some further examples:

[image]

Comment: Nice.. Any reason you don't just post the code corresponding to the image?

Comment: @PeterGrill It's just longish for such a simple detail. Basically I draw two more paths with `..controls (p1) and (p2)..`.