# How to use option fill (fill=white) in a postaction decorate text path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use this command to draw some text along a circular path. But this text overlaps a vertical line (for example). Will I wish that the text appear “in front of” and what is behind the text is thus not visible? How to do that knowing that I use the following code to draw the text?

```
    \path [postaction={ decoration={text along path, text={|\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|THIS END TO NORTH WHEN NORTH OF EQUATOR},text align=center},decorate}]  { (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc (118:60:\RHorizon-.35) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|THIS END TO NORTH WHEN |\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\color{red}\selectfont|SOUTH |\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|OF EQUATOR},text align=center},decorate}]  { (295:\RHorizon-.35) arc (295:243:\RHorizon-.35) } ;
```

The complete code which draws the whole figure is here. One can realize that the text along the path and the vertical line overlap…

```
    % Tracé complet  du tympan d'un astrolabe horizontal d'OUGHTRED
% Author: Dominique COLLIN
%==============================================================================================
% MATERIEL :
% COMPILATION : nécessite un système Tex complet installé sur le disque dur.
%   Tex Live 2012 pour macintosh intel. (http://www.tug.org/mactex/)
%   pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
%   LaTeX2e version < 2011/06/27 >
%   TikZ and PGF sont des packages TeX pour la création de graphiques et dessins programmables.
%   PGF 2012-05-18 CVS build.
%   GNUPLOT version 4.4 patchlevel 3 pour macintoh intel
%   Manuel TikZ = http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-05-18.pdf
%   TeXample.net is a web site dedicated to the wonderful world of TeX and friends.
%   EDITEUR DE TEXTE = TexShop Version 3.11 pour macintosh Intel. (http://www.texshop.org)
% ==============================================================================================
\documentclass[ landscape, a3paper]{memoir}
% ==============================================
    \usepackage{etex}%
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8,applemac]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{cmbright}
%   \usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs,bm}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
% ==============================================
    \usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}%pour le package tikZ et les deux points``:''
    % ------- TikZ packages.
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit,through,intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations} % LATEX and plain TEX when using TikZ
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}% texte le long d'un chemin....
    %
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \usepackage{xifthen}
        % ==============================================
\begin{comment}
:Title: Tracé du tympan d'un Astrolabe horizontal d'Oughtred
:Tags: mathematical engine;geometry;mathematics;ancient astronomy
:Author: Dominique COLLIN
:Slug: astrolabe horizontal d'Oughtred
\end{comment}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\begin{document}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, scale=1]
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
% DEFINITIONS DES CONSTANTES / PARAMETRES MODIFIABLES
%  (Define a few constants for easy configuration and computation)
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
    \pgfmathparse{ 43 + 0/60 + 0/3600 }
\let\latitude\pgfmathresult% Latitude du lieu
% --
    \pgfmathparse{ 23 + 26/60 }
\let\epsilon\pgfmathresult% Déclinaison du soleil au solstice d'été
% --
    \pgfmathparse{ 19.07/2) }
\let\RHorizon\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle horizon dans l'astrolabe d'Oughtred
    \pgfmathparse{ 21.315/2) }
\let\RExterieur\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle horizon dans l'astrolabe d'Oughtred
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
% CALCULS INITIAUX ET DIVERS
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
% -- Les rayons des cercles principaux, des colures des solstices, longueur des divers segments...
    \pgfmathparse{ -cot(\latitude) }
\let\K\pgfmathresult% Constante pour le calcul de l'arc semi-diurne
    \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon*tan((90-\latitude)/2) }
\let\yPole\pgfmathresult% ordonnée du pole nord céleste.
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
% TRACEE DES CERCLES HORAIRES (méridiens célestes)
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
\begin{scope}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\clip circle(\RHorizon+1/150); % limitations de tous les tracés à l'intérieur du cercle de l'HORIZON
% -- -- -- 
    \pgfmathparse{ (\RHorizon*cos(\latitude)/( sin(\latitude)+sin(-\epsilon) ) }
\let\zCh\pgfmathresult% Pour le centre du cercle de déclinaison hiver.
    \pgfmathparse{\zCh+ \RHorizon*tan((\latitude-(-\epsilon))/2) }
\let\RCercleddh\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle de déclinaison hiver.
% --
    \pgfmathparse{ (\RHorizon*cos(\latitude)/( sin(\latitude)+sin(\epsilon) ) }
\let\zCe\pgfmathresult% Pour le centre du cercle de déclinaison ete.
    \pgfmathparse{ \zCe+\RHorizon*tan((\latitude-(\epsilon))/2) }
\let\RCercledde\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle de déclinaison été.
% --
\coordinate (Centreddh) at ( 0, \zCh );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
\coordinate (Centredde) at ( 0, \zCe );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
% -- -- -- afin de limiter les cercles horaires aux solstices d'été et d'hiver :
\clip (Centreddh) circle(\RCercleddh); % limitations de tous les tracés à l'intérieur du solstice hiver
% -- -- -- 
\draw [color=red, line width=.4pt] (Centreddh) circle (\RCercleddh ) ;% Solstice Hiver.
\draw [color=red, line width=.8pt] (Centredde) circle (\RCercledde ) ;% Solstice Ete.
% -- -- --
    \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon*tan(\latitude) }
\let\zi\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du point par où passe la droite contenant les centres des cercles horaires
    \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon/cos(\latitude) }
\let\ipole\pgfmathresult% distance du point i au pôle P
% -- -- -- 
\foreach \H in {0,2.5,5,7.5,...,120}% CERCLES HORAIRES  PM (toutes les 10 minutes))
{%
\ifthenelse{\NOT 0 = \H \AND \NOT 90 = \H}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ \ipole*tan(\H/2) }
\let\iH\pgfmathresult% point de passage du cercle horaire H sur la droite passant par  i
    \pgfmathparse{  \ipole/tan(\H) }
\let\xiC\pgfmathresult% abscisses des centres des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi ou pi.
    \pgfmathparse{  \xiC + \iH }
\let\RcercleH\pgfmathresult% abscisses des centres des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi.
%
\coordinate (CentreH) at ( \xiC, -\zi );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
\draw [color=black, line width=0.1pt] (CentreH) circle (\RcercleH ) ;% Cercle HORAIRE d'angle horaire H.
}{ }%
}% fin de boucle
\foreach \H in {0,-2.5,-5,-7.5,...,-120}% CERCLES HORAIRES AM (toutes les 10 minutes))
{%
\ifthenelse{\NOT 0 = \H \AND \NOT -90 = \H}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ \ipole*tan(\H/2) }
\let\iH\pgfmathresult% point de passage du cercle horaire H sur la droite passant par  i
    \pgfmathparse{  \ipole/tan(\H) }
\let\xiC\pgfmathresult% abscisses des centres des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi ou pi.
    \pgfmathparse{  \xiC + \iH }
\let\RcercleH\pgfmathresult% abscisses des centres des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi.
%
\coordinate (CentreH) at ( \xiC, -\zi );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
\draw [color=black, line width=0.1pt] (CentreH) circle (\RcercleH ) ;% Cercle HORAIRE d'angle horaire H.
}%
}% fin de boucle
% -- Tracé de 10 en 10 degrés : (traits forts)
\foreach \H in {-120,-105,...,+105,+120}% CERCLES HORAIRES AM & PM (toutes les heures pleines)
{%
\ifthenelse{\NOT 0=\H \AND \NOT 90 = \H \AND \NOT -90 = \H}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ \ipole*tan(\H/2) }
\let\iH\pgfmathresult% point de passage du cercle horaire H sur la droite passant par  i
    \pgfmathparse{  \ipole*cot(\H) }
\let\xiC\pgfmathresult% abscisses des centres des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi ou pi.
    \pgfmathparse{  \xiC + \iH }
\let\RcercleH\pgfmathresult% rayons des cercles horaires sur la droite passant par i située à la distance zi ou pi.
%
\coordinate (CentreH) at ( \xiC, -\zi );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
\draw [color=black, line width=0.4pt] (CentreH) circle(\RcercleH );% Cercle HORAIRE d'angle horaire H.
}{ }%
}% fin de boucle
% -- -- -- -- 
% pour le cercle horaire de 90°
    \pgfmathparse{ \ipole*tan(90/2) }
\let\iH\pgfmathresult% point de passage du cercle horaire 90° sur la droite passant par  i
\coordinate (CentreH90) at ( 0, -\zi );%
\draw [color=black, line width=0.5pt] (CentreH90) circle(\iH );% Cercle HORAIRE d'angle horaire 90°.
% -- -- -- afin de limiter les cercles horaires aux solstices d'été :
\filldraw[white] (Centredde) circle(\RCercledde); % pour masquer les cercles horaires compris dans le cercle d'été
% Si quelqu'un a une meilleure méthode pour limiter un tracé (ou un ensemble de chemins) entre deux chemins donnés,
% alors cela serait le bienvenu et certainement plus propre que ce procédé...
% -- -- --
\end{scope}
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- ---
% TRACEE DES PARALLELES CELESTES (CERCLES DE DECLINAISON)
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- ---
\begin{scope}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\clip circle(\RHorizon+1/150); % limitations de tous les tracés à l'intérieur du cercle du tropique du Capricorne (Hiver)
% -- -- --
\foreach \dd in {-24,-22,..., 24}% CERCLES de DECLINAISON
{   \pgfmathparse{ (\RHorizon*cos(\latitude)/( sin(\latitude)+sin(\dd) ) }
\let\zC\pgfmathresult% Pour le centre du cercle de déclinaison dd.
    \pgfmathparse{ \zC+\RHorizon*tan((\latitude-\dd)/2) }
\let\RCercledd\pgfmathresult% Rayon des cercles de déclinaison
%
\coordinate (Centredd) at ( 0, \zC );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
%\fill [black] (CentreAz) circle (1.5pt); % 
\draw [color=black, line width=0.1pt]  (Centredd) circle(\RCercledd); % Tracé du cercle de déclinaison 'dd'
}% fin de boucle
% -- Tracé de 4 en 4 degrés : (traits forts)
\foreach \dd in {-24,-20,..., 24}% 
{   \pgfmathparse{ (\RHorizon*cos(\latitude)/( sin(\latitude)+sin(\dd) ) }
\let\zC\pgfmathresult% Pour le centre du cercle de déclinaison dd.
    \pgfmathparse{ \zC+\RHorizon*tan((\latitude-\dd)/2) }
\let\RCercledd\pgfmathresult% Rayon des cercles de déclinaison
%
\coordinate (Centredd) at ( 0, \zC );% position des différents centres des cercles de déclinaison
\draw [color=black, line width=0.3pt]  (Centredd) circle(\RCercledd); % Tracé du cercle de déclinaison 'dd'
}% fin de boucle
% -- -- --
\end{scope}
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
% TRACES DE CERCLE, DES COURBES ET DES SEGMENTS, des REPERES et QUELQUES POINTS
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
\begin{scope}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\draw [color=black] ( 0, 0 ) circle(\RHorizon); % Cercle de l'horizon du lieu
% -- -- --
\draw [ ] (0,-\RHorizon)--(0,\RHorizon);% Méridien (ligne nord-sud)
\draw [ ] (-\RHorizon,0)--(\RHorizon,0);% ligne Est-Ouest
% -- -- --
\coordinate (z) at (0, 0); % Centre du cercle horizon
\coordinate (P) at (0, \yPole);% Position du pôle nord céleste sur l'axe Nord-Sud
% -- -- --
\fill [black] (z) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage de l'origine, centre de l'astrolabe
\draw[  line width=.005mm] (-0.375 ,\yPole)--(-0.125,\yPole);
\draw[  line width=.005mm] (0.375 ,\yPole)--(0.125,\yPole) ;
\fill [red] (P) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage du Pole nord céleste
% -- -- -- -- -- Repères des trous de fixation
\draw [color=black] ( 0, 0 ) circle (0.8); % Trou central
\fill[color=black] (0,9.9) circle (2pt); % Trou pour la fixation du tympan au nord. 
\draw [color=black, line width=0.1pt] (0,9.9) circle (0.25);
\fill[color=black] (0,-9.9) circle (2pt); % Trou pour la fixation du tympan au Sud. 
\draw [color=black, line width=0.1pt] (0,-9.9) circle (0.25);
% -- -- -- -- -- Cercles 
\draw [color=black, line width=4pt] ( 0, 0 ) circle(\RHorizon+1/10); % Cercle de l'horizon du lieu épais
\draw [color=black, line width=0.01pt] ( 0, 0 ) circle(\RExterieur); % Cercle de l'horizon du lieu épais
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- QUELQUES TEXTES / LEGENDES
\draw [ ] (0,8) node [fill=white] {\fontsize{11.5pt}{11.5pt}\selectfont LATITUDE} ;
\draw [ ] (0,7.15) node [fill=white] { \fontsize{38pt}{38pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textsf{43}}  } ;
%\draw [ ] (0,7.1) node [fill=white] { \fontsize{38pt}{38pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textsf{43\degres 43$^\prime$}}  } ;
%\draw [ ] (0,7.1) node [fill=white] { \fontsize{38pt}{38pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textsf{48\degres 52$^\prime$10$^{\prime\prime}$}}  } ;
%\draw [ ] (0, 6.3) node [fill=white] { \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont Palais de la D{\'e}couverte} ;
\draw [ ] (0, 5.3) node [fill=white] {\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont  MAREAN-KIELHORN} ;
\draw [ ] (0, 4.825) node [fill=white] {\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont  DIRECTOR} ;
\draw [ ] (0, 4.475) node[ fill=white] {\fontsize{4pt}{4pt}\selectfont Ajout{\'e} par D. COLLIN} ;
% -- -- --
\draw[ thick,-stealth ] (2.85 ,1.25)--(4.05,1.25);
\draw[ ] (2.4 ,1.25) node [rotate=180] {\LARGE PM};
\draw[ thick,-stealth ] (-2.8 ,1.25)--(-4,1.25);
\draw[ ] (-2.3 ,1.25) node [rotate=180] {\LARGE AM};
%
\draw[ thick,-stealth ] (2.25 ,-7.6)--(3.35,-7.6);
\draw[ ] (1.7 ,-7.6) node [ ] {\LARGE AM};
\draw[ thick,-stealth ] (-2.25 ,-7.6)--(-3.35,-7.6);
\draw[ ] (-1.7 ,-7.6) node [ ] {\LARGE PM};
%
\path [postaction={ decoration={text along path, text={|\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|THIS END TO NORTH WHEN NORTH OF EQUATOR},text align=center},decorate}]  { (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc (118:60:\RHorizon-.35) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|THIS END TO NORTH WHEN |\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\color{red}\selectfont|SOUTH |\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|OF EQUATOR},text align=center},decorate}]  { (295:\RHorizon-.35) arc (295:243:\RHorizon-.35) } ;
% -- -- -- -- --
\end{scope}
% -- -- -- -- --
%\begin{comment}
%:Title: Degree wheel
%:Tags: Foreach
%A degree wheel inspired by `an example`_ on the `PSTricks website`_.
%.. _an example: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples#compass
%.. _pstricks website: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi
%:Author: Dario Orescanin.
%\end{comment}
%
\begin{scope}% Tracé des graduations des azimuts le long de la circonférence extérieure
% -- -- 
% -- --
\def\radius{\RExterieur}
    \pgfmathparse{ \radius - 0.25) }
\let\onedegrad\pgfmathresult % pour les 1 deg.
    \pgfmathparse{ \radius - 0.35) }
\let\fivedegrad\pgfmathresult % pour les 5 deg.
    \pgfmathparse{ \radius - 0.5) }
\let\tendegrad\pgfmathresult % pour les 10 deg.
    \pgfmathparse{ \radius - 0.9) }
\let\labelrad\pgfmathresult % pour la position des étiquettes... / Elles sont désactivées ici.
% -- --
% main lines
  \foreach \x in {0,...,359} { \draw (\x:\onedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);}
  \foreach \x in {0.5,1.5,...,359.5} { \fill (\x:\onedegrad+.15) circle (0.25pt);}
  % labels and longer lines at every 10 degrees
  \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
  {
    %\node[scale=1, rotate=\x*-1] at (360-\x+90:\labelrad) {\x};
    \draw (\x:\tendegrad) -- (\x:\radius);
  };
  % lines at every 5 degrees
  \foreach \x in {0,5,...,355}  { \draw (\x:\fivedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);}
% -- -- -- -- --
\end{scope}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\begin{scope}[xshift=15cm] % ECHELLE DES HAUTEURS AU-DESSUS DE L'HORIZON
% -- -- -- -- --
    \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon*tan(45) ) }
\let\Zh\pgfmathresult % ordonnée de l'échelle des hauteurs pour h=0°
\draw [very thin ] (0,0) -- (0, -\RExterieur);
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.5pt);
\draw [color=black] ( 0, 0 ) circle (0.8); % Trou pour le positionnement du cercle cartonné et de l'échelle des hauteurs
\clip [draw] (-1.25,1.25) rectangle (1.25,-\RExterieur);
%
\foreach \h in {0,1,2,...,90}%
{   \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon*tan(45-\h/2) ) }
\let\yZh\pgfmathresult % ordonnée de l'échelle des hauteurs tous les 1°
%
\draw [ very thin] (-0.05,-\yZh)--(+0.05,-\yZh);
}% fin boucle
\foreach \h in {0,5,10,...,90}%
{   \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon*tan(45-\h/2) ) }
\let\yZh\pgfmathresult % ordonnée de l'échelle des hauteurs de 5° en 5°
%
\draw [ ] (-0.065,-\yZh)--(+0.065,-\yZh) node [ right] {\tiny \h};
}% fin boucle
\path [postaction={ decoration={text along path, text={|\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont|ALTITUDE SCALE},text align=center},decorate}]  { (-.625,-\Zh)--(-0.625,0) } ;
% -- -- -- -- --
\end{scope}
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

[image]

Comment: I can not help you, but congratulations for the draw. ps: why don't you use a small white circle at that position, only to hide the line?

Comment: I will be able to use this artifice, but I wondered whether there will not exist a means more refined to make and functioning in all the cases…

Comment: Incidentally, if your only use of a path is to decorate it then you don't need to put the decoration in a postaction.

Comment: In your code, I see a lot of `\pgfmathparse{...}\let\xxx\pagmathresult`. Instead of this syntax, you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xxx}{...}`. It is simpler and more readable.

Comment: Dear Andrew Stacey, I use this postaction command because this is the only way to draw a text along a path. I obtained this possibility via this web site by putting the question. It seems that is a good way of doing that. If you have another solution, I am taking… Thank you with you for your remark.

Comment: Dear Paul Gaborit, I will try to use your remark in order to simplify the code. However, I am a poor user of Tikz, and I from time to time need assistance to refine the code. However, thank you with you.

Comment: I added a picture...  But to compile your code, it is necessary to use `scale=.95` (TeX distances can't exceed 5m).

Comment: Thank you. I understand now why the compilation stop. The centers of the hours circles are indeed at long distance from the center of the figure and TeX can't exceed five meters…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I see percusse has a very similar solution, but I'll post mine as well as there are some minor differences.)

```
\begin{scope}
\clip (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc (118:60:\RHorizon-.35) -- ++(0,3) -| 
(118:\RHorizon-.35)  ;
\draw[line width=1.8em,white] (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc
(118:60:\RHorizon-.35);
\end{scope}
\draw[line width=1ex,white] (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc
(118:60:\RHorizon-.35);
\path [decoration={text along path,
text={|\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont|THIS END TO NORTH WHEN NORTH OF
EQUATOR},text align=center},decorate]  { (118:\RHorizon-.35) arc
(118:60:\RHorizon-.35) } ;
```

What this does is similar to percusse's in that it draws the line in white underneath.  Where it differs is in its solution to the problem that the white line is equally spread about the defined line but the text is on one side.  Percusse shifts the text.  What I've done is to clip the line against itself (suitably boxed to make a closed region).  As it's nice to have *some* extension below I then redrew the line (again white) but much thinner.  This solution suffers the same drawback as percusse's in that the white region drawn is as long as the line and not as long as the text.

Given the intricacy of the rest of the code (!), I've not tried for an automatic determination of the widths of the white lines.  An automatic solution is always only ever going to be a rough guess and the precision that seems to have gone into the rest suggests that you are going to want to fine tune these numbers!  It could, though, be wrapped up into a nice command.

Comment: Dear Sir, I understand your solution. It functions correctly. Thank you with you for this assistance.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, each letter goes into an `\hbox` and you can only set the apparent text properties but can not provide each letter to a macro as an argument (in this case `xcolor` package has the `\colorbox{white}{...}` option for background color). So what you can do is to cheat with a double line which I've used also in [Twist a single line matrix in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45836/twist-a-single-line-matrix-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (4,2);
    \draw[draw=white,double distance=1.5ex,double=white,postaction={
    decoration={
    text along path, text=Some long  long text,
    text align=center,raise=-0.25ex
    },decorate
}]  { (3.5,1) arc (60:120:3) } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The apparent disadvantage is that you have to keep your double line short enough that empty white path does not go too far away without a text. Also, you need to adjust the thickness of the line. Nevertheless they are very easy to tune.

Last minute edit: I have added the extra `raise` option which is not shown in the image but is required to center the text with respect to the double line height.

Comment: Dear sir, I tested your solution, but it does not give whole satisfaction. The vertical line is too close to the text.

Comment: @DK06100 You can play around with the values `1.5ex` and `0.5ex` to change the width or the location of the decoration.